# How can i boot 3B+ without SD card holder from scratch

Tags: raspbian, boot, pi-3b+, sd-card, boot-issues

The problem is stable red light when powered up. I think SD car holder is broken. This happened suddenly a week ago. And it doesn't open anymore. Are there any way to open it without sd card holder ? I have SD card reader USB and a 16GB SD card. (3B+)

Comment: If i recall, the 3B+ can boot from USB out of the box - so just plug it in and you should be good to go

Comment: I tried it with SD Card reader from usb socket. But still didn't open. I wonder if I should just do it with usb (I should buy a new) ? Are there any differences between SD card reader (within 16GB SD card) and USB ?

Comment: perhaps the issue is with the sdcard itself if it doesn't work in the sd slot nor with USB SD adapter - do you have another SD card you can write a fresh image on? or do you have a USB thumb drive?